# Tensorflow MNIST for Beginners

Tags: tensorflow

Why do I get different results each time I run the code? Granted, they are all around 92% test accuracy, but seeing as there is no randomness involved (weights are initialized to zero), and sampling the training data does not seem to be random, where could the randomness (resulting in different but close accuracy values) be coming from?

Or could there be something wrong with my installation? Am using an nvidia 960 gtx gpu, and installed TF from sources (version 0.12.head)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the implementation of the `next_batch` function, you'll find it randomly shuffles the data set:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py#L160

Try adding the argument `shuffle=False` to the `next_batch` call.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you. Answered and upvoted. I didn't need to turn off the shuffle, just needed an explanation.  Thanks again!